# Still bug in Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

Let us consider in version 13.1 on Windows 10

```
j = Integrate[2^(I*x)*Log[x]/x, {x, b, Infinity}]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[ Gamma[0, -I a Log[2]] Log[b] -  1/2 \[Pi] (-2 I EulerGamma + \[Pi] - 2 I Log[Log[2]]) +  MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {}}, -I b Log[2]],  Re[b] > 0 && Im[b] == 0]`

and its verification

```
N[j /. b -> 1]
```

> `-5.3833 + 1.018 I`

```
NIntegrate[2^(I*x)*Log[x]/x, {x, 1, Infinity}, Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", AccuracyGoal -> 4,  PrecisionGoal -> 4]
```

> `-0.448496 + 0.356062 I`

This is a simplified case of a bug submitted by me in November, 2017 which is fixed now

```
Integrate[a^(I*x)*Log[x]/x, {x, A, Infinity}]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[ Gamma[0, -I A Log[a]] Log[A] +  MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {}}, -I A Log[a]],  Re[A] > 0 && Im[A] == 0 && Im[Log[a]] > 0]`

The question arises: is there a workaround?

Addition. In version 13.1 on Windows 10

```
k = Integrate[a^(I*x)*Log[x]/x, {x, A, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> a > 1 && A > 0]
```

> `Gamma[0, -I A Log[a]] Log[A] -  1/2 \[Pi] (-2 I EulerGamma + \[Pi] - 2 I Log[Log[a]]) +  MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {}}, -I A Log[a]]`

```
N[k /. {A -> 1, a -> 2}]
```

> `-5.3833 + 1.018 I`

We see the fix is not good.

Comment: It's unfortunate that bugs are still not fixed even after several years/versions. A very common bug that was introduced in v12 related to grouping of cells etc, is also still not fixed either...

Comment: @HansOlo: In the case under consideration  the fix is very badly done. This does not make a good impression about Wolfram Research Inc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workaround with definite integration and taking Limit and assumptions.

```
j1 = Integrate[2^(I*x)*Log[x]/x, {x, b, c}, Assumptions -> 1 <= b < c]

(*   Gamma[0, -I b Log[2]] Log[b] - Gamma[0, -I c Log[2]] Log[c] + 
 MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {}}, -I b Log[2]] - 
 MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {}}, -I c Log[2]]   *)

j2 = Limit[j1, c -> Infinity, Assumptions -> 0 < b < c]

(*   1/24 (12 EulerGamma^2 - \[Pi]^2 + 24 EulerGamma Log[b] - 
   24 CosIntegral[b Log[2]] Log[b] + 12 Log[b]^2 + 
   24 EulerGamma Log[Log[2]] + 24 Log[b] Log[Log[2]] + 
   12 Log[Log[2]]^2 - 
   12 I (-b HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, I b Log[2]] Log[
        4] + \[Pi] (EulerGamma + Log[Log[2]]) + 
      2 Log[b] SinIntegral[b Log[2]]))   *)

j2 /. b -> 1 // N

(*   -0.448495 + 0.356062 I   *)
```

Analog to the other example.

Comment: When executing your `j2`, a warning "Limit::alimv: Warning: Assumptions that involve the limit variable are ignored" appears. The same result  as yours is produced by  `j3 = Limit[j1, c -> Infinity];j3 /. b -> 1 // N`  without any assumptions.